# Retrieving control information from another application from a MouseDown/Up event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on building an application similar to Windows Steps Recorder (WSR) but with more features that are required by my company. I have pretty much done everything but one thing I am struggling on is retrieving the Text/ Names of controls clicked in other applications.

E.g. When using WSR if you click a button labelled OK on another application it can pick this up and automatically makes a comment on that step such as "User left click on OK"

Anyone know how I can retrieve this information using the window handle/ mouse pointer location (x, y)?

Another example I can give is from using the AutoIT Window Info tool

[image: AutoIt Window Info]

As you can see in the figure provided above AutoIt can retrieve the element information within applications using the Finder Tool.

If someone can give me a pointer towards how this is achieved using C# that would be great as currently I don't know where to start. All other examples I have found online are for returning control values from within the application opposed to background applications.

I am building my application in WinForms due to the fact that some of the namespaces I am using aren't compatible with WPF.

Would this be a case of using EnumWindows() and EnumChildWindows()??

**Note:** I do not need help with the mouse hooks etc. simply just the retrival of infromation from a control that has been clicked on.

Thanks, 
Maisy

Comment: [WindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint) + [ChildWindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompoint) + [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation). WPF controls don't have handles, so you'll get the handle of the main Window. UI Automation helps in finding the AutomationElement that contains the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I've managed to retrive the text information. It may not be the prettiest way of doing it but it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EnumChildWinTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public IntPtr windowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;      // Default value

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder title, int size);
        StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(256);


        // Go Button
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox1.AppendText($"Window Handle: {GetWindowHandle(textBox2.Text)} {Environment.NewLine}");

            foreach (var child in GetChildWindows(windowHandle))
            {
                textBox1.AppendText($"Child window: {child.ToString()} {Environment.NewLine}");
                GetWindowText(child.ToInt32(), title, 256);
                textBox1.AppendText($"Title:{title}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
        }

        public IntPtr GetWindowHandle(string processName)
        {

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;
            }

            return windowHandle;
        }

        public List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr handle)
        {
            var allChildWindows = new WindowHandleInfo(windowHandle).GetAllChildHandles();

            return allChildWindows;
        }
    }
}

public class WindowHandleInfo
{
    private delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr lParam);

    private IntPtr _MainHandle;

    public WindowHandleInfo(IntPtr handle)
    {
        this._MainHandle = handle;
    }

    public List<IntPtr> GetAllChildHandles()
    {
        List<IntPtr> childHandles = new List<IntPtr>();

        GCHandle gcChildhandlesList = GCHandle.Alloc(childHandles);
        IntPtr pointerChildHandlesList = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gcChildhandlesList);

        try
        {
            EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
            EnumChildWindows(this._MainHandle, childProc, pointerChildHandlesList);
        }
        finally
        {
            gcChildhandlesList.Free();
        }

        return childHandles;
    }

    private bool EnumWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        GCHandle gcChildhandlesList = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(lParam);

        if (gcChildhandlesList == null || gcChildhandlesList.Target == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        List<IntPtr> childHandles = gcChildhandlesList.Target as List<IntPtr>;
        childHandles.Add(hWnd);

        return true;
    }
}
```